# click() on Modal Button Does Not Close Modal

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am automating the creation of e-sign documents through https://apps.esignlive.eu using Python with Selenium. I have made it most of the way through the process, including attaching the document and assigning the signor. One of the last steps is applying a layout to the document so the signor can provide some information.

When applying the layout, a modal appears and I am able to select the correct layout from a dropdown. Unfortunately, once the "APPLY" button is clicked, a button animation starts and the modal never closes or applies the layout to the document.

I have tried implicit waits, WebDriverWaits, and used Chrome dev tools to make sure I am selecting the correct element. I have tried click() and send_keys() and get the same result. The method is_enabled returns True for the button.

Here is the code I have to process one document.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from time import sleep


file = "C:/Users/<path to file>.docx"

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),
                          options=chrome_options)

driver.get('https://apps.esignlive.eu')
driver.maximize_window()


try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.ID, 'newTransactionButton'))
    )
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'newTransactionButton').click()
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'transaction-name').send_keys('Test')
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'transaction-description').send_keys('Test')
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'btnCreate2').click()
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.ID,
                                             'role-undefined-firstName'))
    )
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'role-undefined-firstName').click()
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'role-undefined-firstName'
                        ).send_keys('Michael')
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'role-undefined-lastName').click()
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'role-undefined-lastName'
                        ).send_keys('Berger')
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'role-undefined-email').click()
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'role-undefined-email'
                        ).send_keys('michael.m.berger@endress.com')
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'transaction-email-message').send_keys(
        'This email may have been sent by ChatGTP, but definitly was not',
        ' sent by Bard. Bard is dumb.'
    )
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.no-outline > input').send_keys(file)
    sleep(2)
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'go-to-designer').click()
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                            '.icon-file-download'))
    )
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.icon-file-download').click()
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.css-ackcql').click()
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.ID, 'react-select-3-input'))
    )
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'react-select-3-input'
                        ).send_keys('Asset Ownership Layout V2')
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((
            By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.info > .text-truncate:nth-child(2)'
            ))
    )
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                        '.info > .text-truncate:nth-child(2)').click()

    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='apply']"))
    )

    print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@id='apply']").is_enabled())driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@id='apply']").is_enabled()
```

This appears to be a React component that has an onclick event listener attached. What could be causing this behavior and what is the work around?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.